# UITableView static cell too long

Tags: ios, uitableview

For `xcode 6.1`, i create a storyboard without 'use auto layout' for iPhone.
In a `UITableViewController` with static cell style, the cell's subviews appears too long.

I set the subviews autosizing mask as `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` in storyboard.

But when print the subview's property in code, i found it's autosizing mask is changed as `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`

how can i fix it? or how can i make the static cell'subviews display as i wish.

Comment: Why not using autolayout?

Comment: Because this project not using auto layout. I just fix some bugs.

Comment: If you are creating a new StoryBoard(mentioned in question), you can make that Storyboard Autolayout without change in existing views.

Comment: I didn't get your point. And now I can't create a new storyboard instead of the old one, it will cast too much time. But thanks still! ^-^